# Getting monitor output during bootup

Tags: startup, monitor

I'm in an unusual spot. The built in screen on the laptop I'm using right now is broken so bad I can barely see anything besides random flickering lights on it. Because of that, I got and plugged in a monitor to my laptop. This moniter works fine once Windows 7 has already loaded.

The issue is: I'm trying to open the BIOS/boot menu to live boot off of my USB, but I can't see anything. How do I make it so that I get visual output on my monitor early enough to open the BIOS/boot menu?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Dell laptop, try FN&F1 or F1

[Dell Forum](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19508313.aspx)